# Button value copy to other button

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

How to get the pressed button title text value and to shows as other pressed button if pressed?i have used the following code to get the title text from button

```
 - (IBAction) checkIt:(id)sender
{
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;


NSLog(@"Button text value %@", button.titleLabel.text);
}
```

How to show the button text into other button if i pressed? Please help me to resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to Create Globle Variable at your app-delegate like:-

**yourAppdelegate.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *buttonTitleCopy;
```

**yourAppdelegate.m**

```
@synthesize buttonTitleCopy;
```

now you just get this variable at your Particular Class like:-

**yourClass.h**

```
#import "yourAppdelegate.h"

//create Object of your Delegate Class

 yourAppdelegate *objAppdelegate;
```

**yourClass.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    objAppdelegate = (REMAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    [super viewDidLoad];


}
```

now in your Method:-

```
 - (IBAction) checkIt:(id)sender
{
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

objAppdelegate.buttonTitleCopy=button.titleLabel.text
NSLog(@"Button text value %@", delegate.buttonTitleCopy);
}
```

now you can use `buttonTitleCopy` variable anywere in your project with app-delegate class Object. Hope your getting this and you solve your issue.

**NOTE:-** just set your OtherButton Title with

`otherButton.titleLabel.text=objAppdelegate.buttonTitleCopy;`

Comment: how to set a button tille on which i pressed

Comment: First set other button title with `otherButton.titleLabel.text=objAppdelegate.buttonTitleCopy;` then you can print it `NSLog(@"Button text value %@", otherButton.titleLabel.text);`

Comment: This feels a bit complex if you are trying to work with two buttons on the same screen. If you have buttons on a different screen that needs updating the 'otherbutton.titleLabel.text' won't quite work unless you want to write som proper spageti code. In the case of buttons on seperate screens you should probably use this solution for storing but then a NSNotification to update the second button.

Answer (score 2):

Do like this,

```
- (IBAction) checkIt:(id)sender
{
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

[your_other_button setTitle:button.titleLabel.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
- (IBAction) checkIt:(id)sender
{

    otherButton.titleLabel.text=sender.titleLabel.text;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get it to point tags or just make a variable button and add it to your button. And get btn text.